# An integer increments strangely in c

Tags: c

Ok, here is the piece of code where I found it strange:

```
printf("di consumerthread : mulai isi data, itmsg = %d\n",itmsg);                               
msgq->data[itmsg]=rec_data;
printf("di consumerthread : selesai isi data, itmsg = %d\n",itmsg);
```

What I found strange is the output:

```
di consumerthread : mulai isi data, itmsg = 42
di consumerthread : selesai isi data, itmsg = 98
```

How come the `itmsg` variable suddenly changes from `42` to `98` after this line?

```
msgq->data[itmsg]=rec_data;
```

Can anybody please tell me how to solve this problem and the cause of this strange output?

Comment: It's possible that `rec_data` is a reference to `msgq->data[itmsg]`, so that assigning to `msgq->data[itmsg]` changes the value of `itmsg`. It's unlikely though.

Comment: Really need to provide some more context here, i.e. what rec_data is, etc. Seems like you might be writing outside of the data array and overwriting itmsg itself.

Comment: Your debug output seems to indicate that threads are happening. Is it possible that `itmsg` was changed in a different thread?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I finally found what's wrong

Sorry if I dont give you enough info because my head is in a mess to explain it in detail..

So, what I did to solve it is:
changing all type of global variable, including itmsg, to static
and all type of procedure and function which use the global variable to static

and it solved all of my problem!

though I still dont know what's static function..

Thanks for all of your help! :D

Comment: It sounds like you found something that seems to fix the problem, but do you understand what the problem was and *why* what you did fixes it?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps msgq->data[itmsg] is an alias for itmsg.  It could happen.  If you inherited this code run a bounds checker on it.

Answer (score 4):

What is the size of the data array? Are you writing off the bounds of it?

It is possible that itmsg is being overwritten by the assignment of rec_data to msgq->data[itmsg]. If they are declared near to each other, this is very possible.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to know for sure based only on the information in your question, the problem could be multiple threads accessing the same memory location (`msgq->data[itmsg]`) at the same time, without any kind of proper synchronization.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have two or more threads that both use the `itmsg` variable? There's nothing in your code snippet that would change the value of that variable, so it looks like it must be another thread that's changing it.

If you're using threads, you'll need to protect any data that they share with a mutex.